# The 'pipe' number cannot be found

Tags: angular, angular7

I just migrated my app from angular 4 to 7, everything works fine, but when it's moment to compile (ng build --prod), I get this error:

```
ERROR in : Template parse errors:
The pipe 'number' could not be found ("
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        {{ listing.currency.abbreviation[ERROR ->]() }}{{ totalCreditRequest() | number : '1.0-1' }}
        <span class="status-badge {{ claims[claims"): /Users/../claims/claims.component.html@50:40
The pipe 'number' could not be found ("m.itemLot.grade }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ listing.currency.abbreviation() }}{{ [ERROR ->]claim.outcomeValue | number : '1.0-1' }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ claim.issue.name"): /Users/../claims/claims.component.html@82:76
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that it was not compiling because of this, can someone explain to me how ivy works and why it's not compiling? I changed it to false and it works now.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
```

Comment: Have you imported `CommonModule` in your Module?

Comment: make sure  your returning the number from totalCreditRequest()

Comment: @madhavsaibhushan It would throw another error if the returned value would be a string or an object.

Comment: Yes, CommonModule is imported in the module, it was compiling fine with Angular 4.

Comment: Angular Ivy (`enableIvy` option) is still at beta. That's something that would come with angular 8 soon. Right now it's in release candidate v3. They changed the too much to cover in this question but you can take a look in this github that some people have problems with the pipes with enableIvy on: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436

Answer (score 1):

You have to import CommonModule, it covers the DecimalPipe

https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  declarations: [...]
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I provided a complete code solution in addition to the simple problem identification @FedericoGalfione

Comment: Thanks @FedericoGalfione, I thought it would be a simple solution as well, CommonModule is imported in the module, it was compiling fine with Angular 4, it doesn't compile properly once I migrated to Angular 7.

Comment: @utiq HAve you figured it out? I'm having the same problem with Angular 11. I don't want to disable Ivy.

Comment: @Ya For me, it's because I was lazy loading a child module, and I accidentaly imported the child routing module in the parent routing module, rather than importing the actual module. (in the loadChildren callback)

Answer (score 0):

If you have able enabled it won't work

"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
}